# How to fix invalid number of arguments in "proxy_set_header" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Tags: django, docker, nginx, proxy, configuration

This is my NGINX reverse proxy development configuration:

```
server {
    listen ${LISTEN_PORT};

    location / {
        proxy_pass                   http://${APP_HOST}:${APP_PORT};
        proxy_set_header Host                                 $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto                  $scheme;
    }
}
```

which I'm receiving the following error for:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "proxy_set_header" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "proxy_set_header" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is the output from docker compose logs